# specification of fixed effects model with time fixed effect and random effects for entity

Tags: r

I am running a mixed effects model on panel data with a time fixed effect (year) and entity random effect (state). I am using the Fatalities data set in R.

The question I have is how to specify the mixed effects model using lmer vs. plm. When I run the random effects model using the plm package, this returns an error

"Error in swar_Between_check(estm[[2L]], method) :
model not estimable: 48 coefficient(s) (incl. intercept) to be estimated but only 48 individual(s) in data for the between model necessary for Swamy-Arora random-effect model estimation".

Since I am only interested in running a random effects model with a random intercept (fixed slope) for state, then I tried another approach following. What difference does this produce between the PLM approach and LMER for **fixed effect for time** and random effects for state?

Is the specification of factor(year) in the LMER package, correct to obtain time fixed effects?

```
install.packages("AER")
library(AER)
data("Fatalities")
summary(Fatalities)


#---PLM model Random Effects
re <- plm(fatal ~ year + state, 
               data = Fatalities, 
               model = "random", 
               index = c("state", "year"))
summary(re)
coef(re)

#---Too few observations error
#---Run in LMER with time fixed effect and random effect for state


#---Model: Fixed slope, random intercept
fatal.re = lmer(fatal ~ factor(year) + (1 | state), data = Fatalities)
summary(fatal.re)
coef(fatal.re)



#------------------------RESIDUALS ESTIMATION-----------------------------------#


#---Obtain prediction residuals from the mixed effects model
fatal.re <- residuals(fatal.re)
fatal.re <- abs(fatal.re)
print(fatal.re)
```